# Error in conditional formatting category labels

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight the following category label in a funnel visual, making it bold or changing its colour while the rest remain like they are:

[image: Funnel visual]

However, upon trying to apply Conditional formatting based on rules (If value is **3-Proposal** then Red) it turns every label to red. I've tried different combinations, with the same results; none would single out one label (worth mentioning I've confirmed there is no typo in the label text). I've also tried applying CF based on field value by adding a customized column that reads "Red" for this category and "Black" for the others, but this only works on a Table visual.

Does anybody know if this is a common issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to format individual Category labels. The conditional format will apply to all the category labels.

It is possible to format individual Data labels with conditional formatting.